# Deferred object returned before it is rejected or resolved?

Tags: jquery, deferred

I have a function that basically looks like this:

```
function defTest()
{
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://XXXX',
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data,status)
        {
            console.log('ajax done: success');
            dfd.resolve();
        },
        error: function(data,status)
        {
            console.log('ajax done: fail');
            dfd.reject();

        }
    });
    console.log('about to return dfd');
    return dfd;    
}
```

I call it like this:

```
defTest().then(.....);
```

The console log produce this:
about to return dfd code.js:106
ajax done: success code.js:96

What confuses me is that the code seems to work. Still the dfd is returned BEFORE the ajax has finished. So i removed the return dfd. And put it last in each ajax handler function to make sure that this will NOT be returned until the Ajax has finished.:

```
success: function(data,status)
{
    console.log('ajax done: success');
    dfd.resolve();
    return dfd;
}
```

Then it didn´t work at all. I am confused! Can someone explain to me why my deferred can´t be in the ajax success and error handlers and why it works even though it seems that my deferred object returns even if it is fired BEFORE the Ajax is finished and then be resolved or rejected? How is that even possible?

EDIT:
This issue is directly linked to my previous unanswered and more complex function:
[Problems with deferred object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365568/problems-with-deferred-object)

This is why i can´t just "return ajax(...)" because my real function contains other ajax calls that will be apart of ONE result handed back to the caller.

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can't return an asynchronous action result from your function which seems like what you're trying to do.

Comment: That is what i am trying to solve using deferred objects.

Comment: `$.ajax` already returns a deferred object as xdazz answered. JavaScript is single-threaded, function calls are synchronous and must return a value (or nothing) synchronously. `$.ajax` is asynchonous. What you can (and should) do is use the ajax success callback to do what you have to do when the ajax request is completed.

Comment: @Fabricio thx for your comment. But i can´t just do return ajax() since it will not solve my problem...have a look at the part i edited in my post.

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax` returns a Deferred object, so you only need to return it.

`return $.ajax(...`

Comment: Yes i know that. But i need to handle it myself. The function is much more complex function in my real code (multiple ajax call). I need to know why my code behave like this.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `defTest` will return as soon as your ajax call is **started**.
It will not wait until deferred is resolved or not.

But you are perfectly able to do what you want:

```
defTest().then(function() { console.log("deferred done"); })
```

It will print `deferred done` when deferred is finally resolved.

By the way, as suggested by xdazz, `$.ajax` returns already a Deferred.

Comment: Yes i know that. But my problem is a little more complex then this function (but the same problem) have a look at my unanswered post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365568/problems-with-deferred-object

Answer (score 1):

there are many questions like this
the `AJAX` request is `async` in nature so in the first example when you were returning it in the last line.
it dosent wait for the `async ajax` to complete
and in the second case the function is already over and putting return in success would obviously not return anything as you are not calling the method assigned to `success` event directly
**UPDATE:- after the comment**
because after returning the `deffered` object you are doing `defTest().then(.....);`
so the function inside the then handler will obviously be fired when the `deffered` object is resolved.
probably you should check the value of the `deffered` object as soon as you return it and not using `.then()` and you will get what mistake you are making here
**Update 2 -** 
have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/BtEKa/ im getting predictable results

Comment: But in my first case that seems to return an resolved or rejected object seems to work. Because even if the console.log seems out of order. I get perfect results everytime. How is that possible?

Comment: Thank you Parv Sharma. But it works. Even if the log say something else. using the return dfd works at the end. The callers success or failure event will be triggered. But how is that possible since it seems (according to the console.log that the return dfd is fired BEFORE the actual ajax statment has finished and making the dfd resolve or reject. How is that possible? The logic should be that the dfd would return a "pending" status since it is returned BEFORE it has been rejected or resolved. It creeps me out a little since i don´t understand how this can be.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/BtEKa/9/
My guess is that because i use an alert() the ajax has time to complete or something like that. So back to step 1. How do i make SURE that i will get a success or failed result to the caller based on the function?

Comment: This problem would have been solved if you could do it like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/2GVbA/1/
But you can´t run return dfd; for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's returned right away, that's the point.  One would be returning the promise member of the deferred object, normally, though -- although you could return the deferred object and use returnedDeferredObject.promise().then() in code that calls this function.

If you have processing that's dependent on the AJAX completion, that processing goes in the .then() function of the returned .promise().  The beauty is in that while the asynchronous processing is going on, you can do other things that aren't dependent on the AJAX return.  You can pass that returned .promise() around to other code.

```
var mydata = somethingThatReturnsPromise(args);

// do a whole bunch of things

mydata.then(function (returnedReponse) {
    // do stuff with returnedResponse that doesn't require DOM ready
});

$(function () {
    mydata.then(function (returnedResponse) {
        // do DOM stuff with returnedPromise
    });
});
```

I hope I'm not missing your point, but I like to think of that returned promise as a data source that I can use again and again later on, and the .then() callbacks I specify will only be executed once there's a returnedResponse.

As a side note, I am pretty sure that with jQuery going more towards the promise standard, .done(), .pipe(), .fail() and .progress() should be replaced with use of .then(successCb, failCb, progressCb).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is that you are returning the entire deferred object, rather than that object's promise.

The promise, afiak, is always returned before the asynch call is returned, so while your last console.log will trigger before the PROMISE is returned, it will happen well before the ajax is resolved.

using .then() is also probably not what you want, since it fires no matter what the status of the deferred object is: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

You probably want .done()

Try this:

```
function defTest()
{
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    $.getJSON("http://XXXX").done(function(data,success){
      console.log('ajax done: success');
      dfd.resolve(data);
    }).fail( function(data,status) {
      console.log('ajax done: fail');
      dfd.reject();
    });
    console.log('about to return dfds promise');
    return dfd.promise;    
}
defTest().done(function(data){ console.log(data); });
```